# Time of response taking too long time - Laravel 6 Api

Tags: laravel, postman

I'm building a laravel API, and I'm testing my requests from Postman. Simple request taking a too long time to get some response(about 132061 ms) and it returns blank. Anyone have any idea what be happening?
[image]

```
   public function register(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
    ]);
 
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Comment: It seems like your server is setup wrong, luckily laravel has inbuilt server, try running "php artisan serve" in your folder, access the localhost with correct ports and see what happens?

Comment: I run php artisan serve and used http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register as url in postman but still doesnot works @mrhn

Comment: Then something is horrible wrong either in a service provider or similar and we need more info to debug it.

Comment: Which file shall I shared? @mrhn

Comment: Instead i would try a whole new project and see if the same occours. There is nothing in your code that should fail tbh

Comment: ok .  Please help me. @mrhn

Comment: can you also look in the laravel log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217167/discussion-between-prabina-sht-and-mrhn).

Answer (score 1):

You set the password to be confirmed in the rules for validation, but the confirmation field doesn't appear in your request. Try again after you removed the '**confirmed**' rule from the rules or add '**password_confirmation**' with same value as password field to your request

Comment: I removed confirmed from the rules but still it doesnot works.

Comment: Are you using the a custom controller or the Auth one's ?

Comment: I'm using custom controller. I'm following this tutorial.https://blog.pusher.com/web-application-laravel-vue-part-2/. @Jdm